# How to change language of spell checker in IE under Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, internet-explorer, language, spell-check

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the spell check and auto-correction language of IE10/Windows8?](https://superuser.com/questions/480540/how-can-i-change-the-spell-check-and-auto-correction-language-of-ie10-windows8)

How do i change the language for the spell checker in a text area in IE 10 on Windows 8 when starting IE as an App?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/480540/how-can-i-change-the-spell-check-and-auto-correction-language-of-ie10-windows8

Answer (score 2):

First, add a language:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
2. Type `Add a language`, hit enter
3. Follow the instructions to add a language

Then go to Charms, Settings (shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) and change the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Sigh. While "input Language" may work for some, it should take all of ten Seconds to realize why many, many, MANY People in fact need to be able to manually override the "cleverness" of their utterly stupid computers. Basically anyone in the world who makes any real use of any Language other than English, for a start. Are we supposed to tell the OS about it every time we switch? Changing the casing may, With a bit of Luck, result in a valid program (i.e. it compiles) that does something other than it was supposed to (crash). Every incorrect capitalization in this comment is an autocorrection!