# Select spell-checking language in Internet Explorer 10, Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, spell-check, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the spell check and auto-correction language of IE10/Windows8?](https://superuser.com/questions/480540/how-can-i-change-the-spell-check-and-auto-correction-language-of-ie10-windows8)

I've got the release Version of Windows 8 installed.

In IE10 it now it automatically checks my spelling. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to control the Language for the spell checking.

I have a Norwegian Laptop - Norwegian keyboard. However, I mostly write in English. The only way so far I've got it to check English is to swap to English input. But this is awkward, because then my keyboard layout is all different.

I also have problems With the spell checked automatically "fixing" my Words. In the middle of sentences it will capitalize the initial character - like just now - "Words" where I typed "words".

I found that under General setting (Charm settings) I could disable the autocorrect, but it doesn't appear to take effect.

**Question 1**

I do like to use spellchecking, but I want to control what Language it's checking against **without changing my keyboard layout**?

**Question 2**

And I Wonder why disabling auto-correct doesn't seem to have any effect?

Comment: .. didn't see that one. But it doesn't answer anything. It all taks about changing the user input. Which is what I want to avoid. I want to choose spelling Language - not keyboard layout.

Comment: It also doesn't answer what's going on With the auto-correction og some of my Words.

Comment: Check the update to my post on the thread Matthew linked to.

Comment: hm... question closed - while Q2 is still a mystery - why the autocorrect was capitalizing some words. And why turning of the feature didn't seem to make any effect...