# I just bought a new Windows 8 desktop computer and there are some problems with keyboard layout

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

Some of the keys were swapped around when I first bought it. Is there any way to swap this back? I've googled it a million times and lots of other people have asked this question with no answers.

Here are the problems:

Shift + 2 = "

Shift + ' = @

Also

Shift + 3 = £ instead of #

Does anyone know the control panel settings to switch this back to normal?

Answer (score 3):

Just search for "Change input methods" in Settings, then select the Options for your language, add and remove the keyboard layout there (you can also preview the layout)

EDIT : You'll want to remove the UK layout, and add US layout

Comment: The screenshots [here](http://superuser.com/a/480566/138343) might help.

Comment: This is correct. UK layout swaps keys. Just use US layout.