# Turn off language check in IE 11?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

When I'm typing something in textboxes like the ones on superuser.com, it underlines almost everything and makes some words uppercase. It seems like it wants to do some spell checking.

My version is 11.0.9600.16428 on Windows 7, German. This didn't happen in previous versions of IE.

I also read about [solving it on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/480540/how-can-i-change-the-spell-check-and-auto-correction-language-of-ie10-windows8), but when I click on "Spell checking", there's no such checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it again to see whether my question description is correct. It seems I just didn't wait long enough for the languages to be populated in the list. After the languages are populated, the checkbox also became visible and I could turn it off.